How to Run Qt Application without sudo When Root Permissions Are Required?
I'm working on a Qt application that accesses certain functions which require root permissions (e.g., accessing hardware resources or certain I/O operations). When I run the application normally, I get the following error:
ERROR: root permission needed.
ioperm: Operation not permitted
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
However, the application runs fine when I execute it with sudo. I don't want to use sudo every time. Is there a way to run this Qt application without needing sudo but still allowing it to access the required privileged functions?

You can make the application executable setuid root. That's how system applications that need root permissions (like sudo itself) are run.
You must change the file owner to root and turn on the setuid bit:
sudo chown root /path/to/my/app
sudo chmod a+x,u+s /path/to/my/app

The u+s argument to chmod is what sets the setuid bit.
BTW. It doesn't matter if it's an Qt application or not, this works for any binary executable file (not a script).

tried this and there was a FATAL error: saying there is a security hole since the app is trying to run setuid. so it didn't help -but thanks!

After a short web search, I found an info about this error and how to fix it: https://linux.m2osw.com/fatal-application-binary-appears-be-running-setuid-security-hole

Heyy! Thanks for the help. This worked. Would you by any chance know that if i am providing root privileges to any app using setuid- this would affect the security of the app and/or system?

I can't know this without knowing your app. It's you, as the person who is writing the app, who must assess the potential risk and built any protection mechanisms into the app, if needed. Regardless if you use setuid or sudo, the risk is the same however.

okayy, got you. Thankss!

You can install lxqt-sudo and create a *.desktop file to launch the program you need as root user.

Install lxqt-sudo


sudo apt update
sudo apt install lxqt-sudo



Create *.desktop app launcher (you can use any text editor for this)


touch ~/.local/share/applications/myrootapp.desktop
nano ~/.local/share/applications/myrootapp.desktop
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/myrootapp.desktop



Paste this content (change xterm to your Qt app)


[Desktop Entry] 
Name=MyRootApp 
Exec=lxqt-sudo xterm 
Terminal=false 
Type=Application 
Icon=xterm 
Categories=System;

In your app launcher, the should be a new program named MyRootApp. A sudo prompt will popup when you launch this

I tried this out but i was trying to avoid any kind of sudo prompt too. I am looking to run some functions from my Qt app that require root permissions but i can't give them continuously atleast. I can set them once or i'd appreciate if there's a way to use setcap such that the error goes away.

If you want to avoid sudo prompt, you can configure the sudoers file so that your app can be run via sudo without asking for password.
